# in average? on average?

Tags: word-usage

I am writing a summary for a facebook campaign, and I want to say "each post reaches over 1000 viewers in average", does it sound right? Should I use "on average" or "in average"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it needs to be asked on ELL. The OP's suggestion of the preposition *in* seems to be based on a non-native tendency. 

Answer (score 15):

If you do [a Google ngram search](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20average,%20on%20average&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) you'll realize starting in the '60s more people had the tendency to use the preposition *on* before *average* although a search in [Corpus Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/) would suggest that the expression *in average* can still be seen in published books nowadays, but they are normally used with *average* as an adjective in sentences like "*There is an increase in average sale.*"

[image]

[image]

Therefore I would advice you to go for the expression "*on average*" instead.

Comment: _On average_ and _on the average_ are identical and mean the same thing. They are adverbial idioms and may appear first, last, or in most adverb niches.

Answer (score 1):

"on (or : on an) average" is sole in use.

Comment: What that opinion, or do you have a reference?

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, Oxford, Collins, and Harrap's

Comment: Then please link to them or otherwise indicate a source. What does "is *sole* in use mean?